# How does one add the results of a regular expression to a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, regex

Imagine a block of code that looks for the regular expression "x is a y" and stores it in some variable. once you have that how do you add them to a dictionary in the format `dict = {y:x, y:x, y:x,...}` ?
examples- "a dog is a canine" "a fox is a canine" "blue is a color" -> `dict ={canine:["dog", "fox"], color:"blue"}`

Comment: Can you show some example ?

Comment: @EXO do you want to do this using regular expression only are can you use other things

Comment: This is really vague. Why would storing the result of a regex in a dictionary be any different from storing anythign else in a dictionary?

Comment: @vigneshkalai I want to do it any way possible

Comment: @DanielRoseman because I'm not storing the whole result and I'm storing it in a specific order.

Comment: @EXO: A dictionary will not maintain order.

Answer (score 2):

With the given requirements, it is not necessary to use regex - it is a bit overhead. You can solve your task with almost a one-liner by using a built-in *setdefault()* method with *append()* and *split()* and *list comprehension*.

```
input = [ "a dog is a canine", "a fox is a canine", "blue is a color"]
output = {}
[output.setdefault(v, []).append(k) for k,v in (s.split(' is a ') for s in input)]
print(output)
```

> {'color': ['blue'], 'canine': ['a dog', 'a fox']}

Comment: if you always have 'a ' in input strings you can simply strip two first symbols from them: [output.setdefault(v, []).append(k) for k,v in (s[2:].split(' is a ') for s in input)] you can notice s[2:] , that means 'slice' that string after 2 character

Comment: can I talk to you privately? I wish to create something however I am a philosopher not a coder and I don't have the coding skills to finish or even start my project.

Answer (score 1):

If the form is always 'x is a y' you can use split(). Then its only a matter of checking if y is already in your dictionary and adding accordingly. Check the following example:

```
dict = {}
phrases = ['dog is a canine', 'wolf is a canine', 'blue is a color']
for phrase in phrases:
    x, y = phrase.split(' is a ')
    if y not in dict:
        dict[y] = []
    dict[y].append(x)
print dict
```

will print

> {'color': ['blue'], 'canine': ['dog', 'wolf']}

Comment: sorry, it isn't because it can be in the form "an x is a y".